# Ethernet Network not showing or connecting in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, lan

I updated from 16.04 to 17.04 a couple days ago. After doing so I found that when I connect my Ethernet cable, it doesn't connect or show connection as it did in 16.04. I Have an HP-15 laptop. I checked for drivers in update area, but it didn't find anything related to Ethernet network.

Here is what I did:
To do this - in a terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

change the line managed=false to managed=true

Save, stop and start network manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But still have the problem.

It looks like it tries to connect to LAN wired connection but then goes directly to WiFi and connects, then doesn't show any Ethernet connection like it did in 16.04.  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm almost ready to revert to 16.04

Comment: [main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

Comment: Went there followed the directions, rebooted and still no ethernet connection showing.

Comment: # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53

Comment: systemd-resolve --status
 the out put is to big to post in this.  I followed that links instructions earlier didn't work.

Comment: you can post the output at  [Paste Ubuntu](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and link it in the question, also update the information that we discussed in the comments to your question and delete comments

Answer (score 54):

According to this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1638842), the solution is to add a missing configuration file to NetworkManager, then to restart it.

It worked for me :

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Comment: That worked for me as well. 2 1/2 years later though. Is this still a bug???

Comment: After so much struggle. THANK YOU!

Comment: Thanks for this. I was missing the config after having installed Ubuntu 20.04 while using a wireless adapter, and later removed the wireless and had no ethernet. I could get a connection temporarily with `sudo dhclient enp2s0` and `service network-manager restart` but it would disappear again after restart. Adding the globally managed devices conf file resolved it for me.

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04. Unfortunately this did not work for me.

Comment: After 5 years, it still exists.

Answer (score 11):

Open an Terminal window.  There are many different methods for this.  The easist is to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> at the same time.

**Step 1** Type in or copy this command: `sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`  Then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  Now type in your user password and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key again.

**Step 2** Do the same for this command: `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`

Answer (score 7):

I entered this into terminal:

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
```

entered and then rebooted and it is there.

Comment: This fixed my problem. My Ethernet adapter was completely missing from ifconfig output but is available now.

Comment: This fixed my problem also...in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. So I give you an upvote.

Answer (score 4):

For temporary solution use

```
sudo dhclient
```

Comment: This command actually made my ethernet connection come back alive after I've broken it using autoremove...

Answer (score 1):

**Ethernet Network not showing or connecting in Ubuntu 18.04**

It  is working fine.
Just open the terminal and update the system using WiFi-connection:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After compliantion of the update

```
clear
```

Now open the New terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

change the line managed=false to managed=true

Save, stop and start network manager:

if you find any problem else more try this:

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf

sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Comment: Tried this. Did not solve anything. Why is it supposed to work. What is the meaning of managed=true. Why is it not the default if it is better?

Comment: @Kvothe This indicates that the network or device is managed by NetworkManager.