# Ubuntu 18.04 missing wired connections in settings

Tags: 18.04, network-manager

I have installed 18.04 Ubuntu Server.
Then in terminal installed:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

and when I now log into the desktop gui, my network shows as unmanaged at the top right, and in settings I do not get any wired settings options, why is this?
[image]

I ran:

```
sudo lshw -c net
```

and had to take a picture of the results for the moment:
[image]

Comment: Use the `lshw -v` command to dump your hardware info as text. Locate the section detailing your ethernet hardware. Edit your question to include the complete output of that section. We're looking for the manufacturer, *exact* model number, and whether or not a kernel module (driver) is active.

Comment: @user535733 Updated the question with the net information from lshw, but unfortunately I had to take a pic of it.

Comment: Make sure it's plugged into the network, then run `ip addr` to see if it has an IP address. If so, then ping somebody. If it works, then reboot and see if it still works.

Comment: @user535733 I have tried all that, I can ping google.com fine.

Comment: So it's JUST the missing Gnome Desktop setting? Everything else works?

Comment: @user535733 Yes I believe so

Answer (score 25):

I had this same issue which seems to be an [Ubuntu NetworkManager bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1638842). I was able to solve my problem by adding a missing config file and then restarting the NetworkManager as follows:

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908614/ethernet-network-not-showing-or-connecting-in-ubuntu-17-04) lead me to this solution, which I am posting here in case it helps you. Credit to skizo for finding something that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Missing wired connections in settings:

**Establish pppoe connection in Ubuntu:** 
It's possible to bypass this problem using nmcli command.
Create connection:

```
nmcli con edit type pppoe con-name "Connection name"
```

Set a username:

```
set pppoe.username <username>
```

Set a password:

```
set pppoe.password <password>
```

Save and quit:

```
save
quit
```

[And this link is help you in details.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193856/how-to-establish-pppoe-connection-in-ubuntu/1205865?newreg=457480672b22413eaabc90b7a70ea166)