# using GUI the "DSL" tab in NetworkManager is missing

Tags: pppoe

was trying to setup DSL connection in the NetworkManager but only the VPN option is available in the NetworkManager GNome.

please advise, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to establish pppoe connection in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193856/how-to-establish-pppoe-connection-in-ubuntu)

Comment: sorry, didnt see anything thats says how to display the DSL connection tab in the NetworkManager

Comment: It does. You run commands and then it should be shown. Read the accepted answer.

Comment: sorry, which commands?

Comment: tried these set of commands:

Comment: nmcli con edit type pppoe con-name "Connection name" etc

Comment: still the "DSL" option in the NetworkManager didnt appear

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what exactly you did and what is the problem. It should work.

Comment: tried again, option showed in the the advanced network config