# Ubuntu 20.04 Network issues

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Each time that I start the pc and log into my account the ethernet Connection doesn't work and the ethernet icon does not appear in the top-bar.

> cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml output:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

> if I run `sudo lshw -C network` i get the following output

```
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 0c
       serial: e0:3f:49:46:0b:53
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:18 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7100000-f7100fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
```

I saw that i had to put it's logical name inside the `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
```

toggle the `managed` field inside `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

and reboot.

I did so but didn't work.
The only way that is currenty working is to run `sudo dhclient` but i have to run it at each reboot. What can i try for a perma solution?

Comment: The internet icon doesn't appear because you've changed `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: It wasn't appearing also before changing it, it was an empty file

Comment: It shouldn't be an empty file either.

Comment: if you click on the ethernet conection and go to settings for wired connection  is there a tab that say connect automatic is this on or off.

Comment: I have nothing about ethernet connection in the settings, only wifi

Comment: Is this a desktop or server installation? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: @heynnema i edited the question with your rqeusts

Comment: I've put together an answer that requests a couple of edits, and points out a possible cable problem. Please review and report back.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had to follow the steps given in  [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088953/ubuntu-18-04-missing-wired-connections-in-settings)

Basically run these two commands

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Comment: This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and post there ONLY

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

The network device will be controlled by Network Manager, and you'll have the settings back.

When you add entries to this files, it disables Network Manager.