# My Ubuntu client says that the wired connection is unmanaged

Tags: netplan, connection, wired

This is what is showing when I look at the wired management. I don't know what I did that it's showing all of these and I can no longer access the internet.

[image]

Comment: Try "sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager" command

Comment: Where is the question all I see is a link.

Answer (score 0):

These two steps should make the wired connection managed, as found [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1278959/323551)

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```