# can't ping outside, but curl wget works

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables, ping

I'm setting up a new server and this is driving me nuts.

I use a static IP, and have set it up correctly.

I can curl [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), wget driver files, apt install, use teamviewer.

But I can't remotely ssh using port 22 (or any other port)

I can't also ping/tcptraceroute anywhere besides the servers within my gateway. even 8.8.8.8 is unreachable.

I have 2 lan ports, and currently enp5s0 is connected.

below is my ifconfig -a

```
enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 114.70.37.242  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 114.70.37.255
        inet6 fe80::264b:feff:fe8c:7cc4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 24:4b:fe:8c:7c:c4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5708481  bytes 5108244101 (5.1 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 132234  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 469442  bytes 192375552 (192.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0x94300000-9437ffff  

enp6s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 24:4b:fe:8c:7c:c5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0x94200000-9427ffff  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 243577  bytes 246215414 (246.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 243577  bytes 246215414 (246.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

my tcptraceroute 8.8.8.8

```
Selected device enp5s0, address 114.70.37.242, port 50637 for outgoing packets
Tracing the path to 8.8.8.8 on TCP port 80 (http), 30 hops max
 1  _gateway (114.70.37.254)  0.701 ms  0.671 ms  0.621 ms
 2  192.168.10.37  78.193 ms  0.693 ms  0.681 ms
 3  192.168.201.2  0.389 ms  0.222 ms  0.197 ms
 4  * * *
```

I have ufw disabled, iptables -F has been executed so iptables -L shows nothing.

can anyone help me out please?

edit =============
results of route as well

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp5s0
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp5s0
114.70.37.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp5s0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google generally limits pings and other non-resolution traffic to `8.8.8.8` as it’s a DNS service rather than an Internet connection test. As you’re able to use cURL and other things, your DNS is clearly working as is the connection to the outside world. Are you able to ping `151.101.1.69` (AskUbuntu)?

As for the SSH problem, have you confirmed the port is not being blocked by the router or some other network device?

Comment: thank you for taking your time to annswer!
as for pinging askubuntu, nope, no other addresses outside of 114.70.37.* are reachable.

I am checking other things but haven't found anything blocking the port..

Comment: it was driving me crazy, so I came to the PC's physical location.
The GUI browser (firefox) works just fine, but the weird thing is, in the settings - network, I have no wired connection menu. there is only a VPN menu..isn't wired connection menu with a settings-like cog wheel button supposed to be there?

Comment: (Solved) You were right, I have talked with the network admin, and it seems it was on their end that the SSH from outside was blocked.

I forgot to ask them about the ping issue, but as all else is working, I assume it's blocked on the admin side of my building.

As for the missing wired connection in the GUI settings, I was able to fix this bug with https://askubuntu.com/a/1125111/1164731

Comment: Excellent! Glad you could get to the bottom of the issue 