# Ubuntu 18.04 suddenly no sound and no wifi

Tags: 18.04, wireless, sound

I've been using ubuntu 18.04 since I got this Dell laptop in 2018. I don't have any dual thing, just ubuntu. Yesterday suddenly sound is gone and only Dummy Output is shown in settings, but I still had wifi. Now wifi and bluetooth (I never use bluetooth anyway) are also gone - "no wifi adapter found" in settings. What is happening to my system? More importantly how can I fix this (please gear simple, straightforward answer for non-tech person)

Comment: What changes have you made to your system since the lad time everything worked? Does your laptop have a mistakenly pushed "Airplane" switch? Or a WiFi or Bluetooth button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: There was no wifi switch at all when that happened, later I got wifi back, then I found that if I turned it on unplugged I could get sound back. But now I have a much worse problem, because I thought I could fix all these issues by upgrading to 20.04, and it finally seemed like I'd gotten the upgrade going but then this somehow completely crashed my computer, I've been trying for hours now to fix it and nothing works!

Answer (score 0):

Tried to get started with work today and ran into the same issue.  I found this and was able to get wireless back up. Sound is not as much of a priority for me but if I find something out I'll follow up here.

[Ubuntu 20.04 - network DISABLED](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341472/ubuntu-20-04-network-disabled)

I bet there was some kind of recent driver update that dorked things up.

**UPDATE**

It looks like this is just a bad kernel version. If you run `uname -a` in a terminal and it shows `4.15.0-177-generic`, then you have the bad kernel version.  Reboot and [get into your grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version) and select any version prior to 4.15.0-177.  I selected 4.15.0.176 and audio, wifi, and bluetooth are all back on.

Comment: Here's a bug tracker for this issue.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1973167