# network disabled after installing ubuntu server on virtual machine

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, network-manager

I installed ubuntu server downloaded from [here](https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-arm64.iso) Then I found network is disabled:
[image]

Besides, I found the network-manager was missing after I tried to restart the network-manager according this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341472/ubuntu-20-04-network-disabled). when I enter

```shell
$ sudo service network-manager stop
```

it prompted: `Unit network-manager.service not loaded`.
So how to work around it without any wifi connections?
My desktop is apple macbook pro with m1 chip, and I use VMWare Fusion.

**Edit**:
output of `ip a`:
[image]

Comment: Is the network disabled in the VM or on the host? 

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the complete output of `ip a`

Comment: @user535733 hey, I update it, please check it

Comment: Try `sudo ip link set dev ens160 up`. That's it on the Ubuntu side -- everything looks set up properly. As @Matigo said, check VMWare on your MacOS side to ensure that networking is turned on. That side is where all the magic happens.

Comment: @user535733 it works for me! network enabled. I am really a noob to networking. Maybe I need ping something to test whether it connected

Comment: Keep in mind that your MacOS is doing all the real networking. The VMWare application on the Mac is providing a *virtual* ethernet port for your *virtual* server to use. That ethernet port is all your server can see, regardless of whatever networking adventures are happening on the MacOS side. Your VM server does not know that it's on a laptop, and will never see any of your real-life networking interfaces. That's why you don't need NetworkManager.

Comment: That virtual ethernet port is `ens160`, and that came from entry #2 in your `ip a` output. Note that same line also said `state DOWN`, which is why you used a command to bring it up. It's pretty much that simple on the Ubuntu Server side.