# Ethernet disabled Lenovo Legion 5, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wired

My wifi is working fine. However, when I try to connect using the ethernet, I get no connection. The ethernet is not even present in the settings. I'll list the output of some commands below, along with the things I tried.

ifconfig:

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:4e:cb:fe:fa  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1904  bytes 174018 (174.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1904  bytes 174018 (174.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:44:21:93  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp0s20f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::d111:7e77:a0f3:6d41  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fdd8:2918:dfd6:ef00:34c6:a262:f72d:577b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fdd8:2918:dfd6:ef00:2484:510:129e:4f1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 84:1b:77:99:ba:ab  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 24965  bytes 29016731 (29.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13800  bytes 2260811 (2.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"HazemNetwork"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Access Point: D8:29:18:DF:D6:F8   
          Bit Rate=58.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:90   Missed beacon:0

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

nmcli d:

```
DEVICE             TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION   
wlp0s20f3          wifi      connected     HazemNetwork 
docker0            bridge    connected     docker0      
virbr0             bridge    connected     virbr0       
p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3  wifi-p2p  disconnected  --           
enp7s0             ethernet  unmanaged     --           
lo                 loopback  unmanaged     --           
virbr0-nic         tun       unmanaged     --
```

sudo lshw -c net:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 00
       serial: 84:1b:77:99:ba:ab
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-59-generic firmware=55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.u ip=192.168.1.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:b2498000-b249bfff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 15
       serial: 8c:8c:aa:b5:61:4e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-59-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b2204000-b2204fff memory:b2200000-b2203fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:44:21:93
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

I tried using the network manager through this command: nm-connection-editor. And I added the ethernet connection. However, it didn't work as well.

I tried using [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1125111), and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/882812). But nothing worked.

I don't know how, but I have a feeling that this docker connection has something to do with it.

I hope that someone will find a solution. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that your Ethernet is disabled

This may help:

```
sudo ifconfig enp7s0 up
sudo nmcli dev set enp7s0 managed yes
```

Then restart NetworkManager:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and your help... I tried these commands, and I still have no connection. The only thing changed is, there is now an option that says "wired unmanaged" in my status bar (the one with logout option). And still no wired option in settings.

Answer (score 0):

We can connect to the Internet via your phone's USB modem or directly plug in the cable for convenience.
Then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git
cd rtw89
make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/firmware/rtw89
sudo cp  rtw8852a_fw.bin  /usr/lib/firmware/rtw89/
sudo modprobe rtw89pci
```

After these steps, you can select Internet in the Wi-Fi menu.