# No LAN connection anymore

Tags: networking, 20.04, lan

I don’t know what I or any update did since yesterday, but after booting today I no longer have LAN connectivity (no internet, no ethernet).

My Win10 install on the same machine does, another ubuntu20.04 LTS install also does (both on other drives).

So it's not my hardware that is failing.
Some things I have tried from other questions did not work.
(https://askubuntu.com/a/909442/1030659)

I don't have a History of which questions I looked at, but I can share my [zsh history](https://gist.github.com/joshinils/52605b9ab5257ae6c50d8b8b78ef4fe2) since no connection.

I don’t know my way around so I don’t understand what the problem cold even be. I’d appreciate it if someone could walk me through this issue, I do not want to reinstall ubuntu.

```
➜  ~ rfkill
➜  ~ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:4b:fe:07:14:58 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: ham0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1404 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7a:79:19:2a:f1:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 25.42.241.163/8 brd 25.255.255.255 scope global ham0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2620:9b::192a:f1a3/96 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7879:19ff:fe2a:f1a3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
➜  ~ route
zsh: correct 'route' to 'routel' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: route
➜  ~
```

[gist: /var/log/apt/history.log](https://gist.github.com/joshinils/836154ab7b12fea48ead5bc2044f6ca9)

Comment: Interesting, well i mean the 20.04 LTS desktop one.

Comment: You can get better help if you explain what you tried that failed, including the results that lead you to believe that it failed. It's not clear what you mean by "LAN connectivity." Does that mean that you can access the internet but not your LAN? Does that mean your wired connection does not work but your wireless does?  The list of updates, and the day each was applied, is in /var/log/apt/history.log. Your updates yesterday are likely to be different from mine, so look up *your* updates. It's not clear what leads you to believe that an update is responsible. May be other possible causes.

Comment: Also please edit your question to show us the complete output of `rfkill` and of `ip addr`and of `route`.

Comment: No, I have no connectivity to either my router nor the internet. I don’t have wifi capabilities on this machine.

Comment: @user535733 should I censor any of the output? Does that make sense?

Comment: There is nothing in the output worth censoring. Since you seem to be describing a mysterious failure of a wired connection, the first thing I always test is the cable. Folks *never* admit that they rolled over or pinched or yanked a cable...but they did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115892/discussion-between-josh-and-user535733).

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing the r8168 driver for my Realtek ethernet device.
Which (now) is:

```
➜  ~ lspci -v | grep Ethernet -A 7
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 26)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 59
    I/O ports at f000 [size=256]
    Memory at fc804000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at fc800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8168
    Kernel modules: r8168
```

by following this guide: https://tuxbyte.com/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/

To do that I used another (working) Ubuntu install and downloaded the package;
`apt download r8168-dkms`. After installing this and rebooting I still have no connectivity.

Hence I tried this (thinking that maybe the other driver works "better"):

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

And now I have Internet again.

Oh and I had to restart my pulseaudio.
`pulseaudio -D` and re-select my headphones as output device.

Comment: ok, now i need to restart pulseaudio after every reboot... :(