# Ubuntu 20.04 - Realtek Ethernet lost after reboot

Tags: networking, ethernet, realtek

I'm fairly new here in Ubuntu. I'm running a 20.04 LTS with kernel ver. of 5.85.8.0-40-generic.

Previously (around a day ago), I managed to 'achieve' an ethernet connection via Realtek thanks to a certain guy residing here. However, when I reboot'd today, I lost my ethernet connection. I tried to resit the cable but still won't work. :/

I checked first previous posts in this forum (dated 3 years ago lol) and run the same process -> [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908614/ethernet-network-not-showing-or-connecting-in-ubuntu-17-04)...

What I did in the terminal is;

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

changed the line managed=false to managed=true. Then;

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

The problem still persists. So I tried to restart the network manager via,

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

And it still doesn't work afterall. Are there any workarounds for this one? Any help is sincerely appreciated at this point. :c

Regards,

astro_cgha, aavso

*EDIT: I also run sudo apt-get update via a Tethered connection from my phone as a temporary sol'n lol.*

Comment: "I managed to 'achieve' an ethernet connection via Realtek" What exactly did you do? Did you install a driver? Which? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I apologize since I didn't reply back. But what I mean is 'set-up' the ethernet connection in Ubuntu before...However, for some unknown reason, it got lost. Since, I checked previous soln and none was able to resolve it in my case, I just do a fresh install of Ubuntu and re-do some 'processes' which requires initially a tethered connection lol.

Comment: "I just do a fresh install of Ubuntu" Is this where the ethernet is *not* working? Please clarify.