# Internet connection broken after installing VPN

Tags: networking, server, ssh, network-manager, vpn

I installed https://hide.me VPN on my Ubuntu 22.10 server.

https://github.com/eventure/hide.client.linux

I was using XRDP to control the server with a GUI.
After I enabled the VPN, the XRDP connection was immediately cut off.

When the VPN is connected, my RDP / SSH connections dont seem to go through. The only way I was able to regain access to the machine was via https://linode.com's web SSH client (and also be just restarting the machine to kill the VPN).

Because I can't work properly with this VPN, I decided to abandon it; I uninstalled the VPN (and stopped/disabled its services - and have rebooted).

But now, the internet isn't working anymore. Unlike before, all my attempts to connect to the internet (`curl`, google chrome, etc) fail. The only way I've been able to access the internet from the machine is by re-enabling the VPN (which then prevents me from SSH'ing / RDP'ing).

The weird thing is, I can still SSH and RDP into the machine right now - so obviously the machine is connected to the internet - but I think the apps like `curl` and Chrome are trying to connect to the internet through a non-existing VPN.

I've tried different things with ethernet/network configurations.
For example, doing some searching online I saw other users had an "ethernet" device showing in their settings, but my machine didn't, so I ran:

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

From [Ethernet Network not showing or connecting in Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908614/ethernet-network-not-showing-or-connecting-in-ubuntu-17-04)

That then started showing an ethernet device, but still no internet working.

---

Here's the result of me running: `resolvectl status`

```
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: foreign
Current DNS Server: 10.128.86.1
       DNS Servers: 10.128.86.1 fd00:6968:6564:2b::1

Link 2 (eth0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 151.236.217.42
       DNS Servers: 151.236.217.42 88.80.186.183 176.58.116.5
        DNS Domain: members.linode.com
```